# SUM lots of half hourly data into a separate list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I currently have generation data over half-hourly time intervals. However there are about 70 entries for each half hour. What I want to do is make a column that aggregates all the generation for each time interval.

[image: excel file]

Currently my approach is this `=SUM(D2:D71)` and then in the next cell `SUM(D72:D144)` etc. Surely there must be a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can create a pivot table

Ctrl + a your data  -  Insert - create pivot table

put the interval number in the [Rows] field and put the Energy generated in [Values]

Answer (score 1):

SUMIFS would seem to be useful.

```
=sumifs(d:d, c:c, ">="&a2+time(8, 0, 0), c:c, "<"&a2+time(8, 30, 0)
=sumifs(d:d, c:c, ">="&a2+time(8, 30, 0), c:c, "<"&a2+time(9, 0, 0)
=sumifs(d:d, c:c, ">="&a2+time(9, 0, 0), c:c, "<"&a2+time(9, 30, 0)
=sumifs(d:d, c:c, ">="&a2+time(9, 30, 0), c:c, "<"&a2+time(10, 0, 0)
'etc ...
```

The time sequence could likely be resolved with a ROW() function that advances when filled down.

If you copied column C to a new unused column (e.g. column H) and removed duplicates then this should suffice.

```
=sumifs(d:d, h:h, ">="h2, h:h, "<"&h2+time(0, 30, 0)
```

Comment: when you say remove duplicates, there are about 72 duplicates for each time interval. However they are not really duplicates, as the energy is different for each one, as each one corresponds to a different plant. So I don't think this will work unfortunately, thanks for trying though

Comment: No, you only copy column C and use Data, Remove Duplicates. The idea is to get a list of unique datetimes that sumifs can reference to resolve the totals for each unique datetime.

Comment: That makes sense actually, thanks. Pivot tables just seems easier though